# How to convert string into HTML string?

Tags: javascript, php, html, string

I have a string(variable) having value of database cell. Actually that value is html code. I have to print that code into html page. I found that how to convert HTML string into DOM string. But I don't know that How to convert string into HTML string. If anyone know answer then please explain or suggest me link from where I can understand from beginning. Thank You. Here is my code.

```
<?php
$dbstr = mysql_escape_string("&lt;p&gt;Just install and use this app.&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;MENU -&amp;gt; SETTINGA&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fun(str) {
            var div = document.getElementById('htmldiv');
            div.innerHTML = str;
            var elements = div.childNodes;
        }
    </script>
    <div id="htmldiv">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            fun('<?php echo $dbstr; ?>');
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

I get out put like this.
[image]

But I want like this.
[image]

Comment: When you have any doubt regarding strings in php, take a look at this list of functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php . You'll find the function you are looking for, and you will learn about everything you can do with many others.

Comment: Try this `html_entity_decode` in place of `mysql_escape_string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$dbstr = html_entity_decode("&lt;p&gt;Just install and use this app.&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;MENU -&amp;gt; SETTINGA&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    $dbstr = htmlspecialchars_decode("<p>Just install and use this app. <strong>MENU -> SETTINGA</strong></p>");

echo $dbstr;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the tags get printed and not interpreted is, that with using the html special char coding (`&lt;` and `&gt;`) you are actually telling the browser that you want the special chars to be printed, not interpreted.
Since you are retrieving this from a database, changing the actual content might not be the best idea or not even possible. Instead, you can decode the special chars with a built in php function:

```
$dbstr = htmlspecialchars_decode(mysql_escape_string("&lt;p&gt;Just install and use this app.&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;MENU -&amp;gt; SETTINGA&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dbstr = html_entity_decode("&lt;p&gt;Just install and use this app.&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;MENU -&amp;gt; SETTINGA&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;");
echo $dbstr;
```

use `html_entity_decode()` function

[html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)